# Is it possible to create a configuration profile "on" iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, config, configuration-files, wifi

I am trying to create a configuration profile dealing with wifi settings on iphone. I know I can do it using Apple Configurator 2. But I wonder if it is also possible to create one and install on ios application.

I have googled for a while but I couldn't find any clue about it. However, I found an application called "WiFI Priority" (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-priority/id963277048?mt=8) which does exactly what I wanted. Any idea about how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for something similar, but the task turned out to be not actual. I've got some thoughts which you can probably find useful:

1. You can generate configuration profile manually on device. It's just an XML file named YOUR_NAME.mobileconfig.
2. Start an on-device file server and make it return the generated file for some port (maybe you find a better solution). I used to work with GCDWebserver and was very satisfied.
3. Run a WKWebView, go to URL: localhost/port, you'll get the ability to install the generated file.

P.S. It's just a set of few thoughts based on my indirect experience regarding the question, but I hope it may help someone who reaches this page, as it has no answers or comments. If I have time, I'll try to test this solution and post the code on GitHub.